# How do I replicate Excel Solver to solve for a specific output in R?

Tags: r, solver

I think this should be a simple problem, but I am struggling to find a solution elsewhere. I have a function with several inputs. I would like to be able to find the value of a single input that results in the function returning 0 given constants for the other inputs.

simplified version:

```
funct = function(x,y) {x+y

}
```

Given a value of 10 for x, I would like R to solve for what y would need to be to return the value of 0 for the function. Is there a simple way to solve these optimization/solver challenges?

Comment: See the `ompr` package: https://dirkschumacher.github.io/ompr/index.html  Models are formulated algebraically with the paradigm, so it is easy to learn.  Questions can be posted on GitHub: https://github.com/dirkschumacher/ompr/discussions

Comment: You could also try `uniroot`, e.g. `uniroot(funct, c(-100, 100), y = 10)`